# 2013 - Populate column based on another value in datasheet view

Tags: 2013, list, datasheet

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

I'm trying to understand if is it possible to populate a column when another column is filled in datasheet view.

I mean: I have a SharePoint list with "Start Date" and "End Date". When the "Start Date" is selected, I want to complete the "End Date" with a date that will be like StartDate + 1 month.

This is not a big problem with jQuery in a new form, but this list is mainly modified using the datasheet view.

I've searched the internet, but found only solution based on jQuery/NewForm.

So is it possible to populate "End Date" automatically on the datasheet view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you do not need any custom code to achieve this.

1. Create a Calculated Column Called 'End Date' with the formula

   [Start Date]+30
2. DataView enter the data for the Start Date and End Date will automatically get populated[image]

`

Comment: In this way the "End Date" column is populated only when the item is saved. Is there a way to populate the field after the user insert/select the Start Date value? An user should be able to change the "End Date"

Comment: This is what exactly happening. Did you try this? End Date is read only, changed when start date gets changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Uhm, I'm trying on my test environment and I can get the "End Date" value only when item is saved, and not when I change column after I have selected the "Start Date" . Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What is the type for End Date column?  It should be calculated column returning Date/Time

Comment: I can confirm you that "End Date" is a calculated column and it returns "Date/Time".

Comment: Do you mean that when you change the Start Date, End Date doesn't populate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59277/discussion-between-s-merchant-and-pepozzo).